# How to create a table with inet type in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Can someone please provide a minimal working example of a table in postgres SQL using  the [inet data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-net-types.html). I can't find a single one anywhere on the internet and I get the following error when running the following

```
CREATE TABLE host (
     id                        serial primary key,
     ip_address                inet,
     "timestamp"               date DEFAULT ('now'::text)::date
 );
```

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: inet ~ unknown
>
> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: What PostgreSQL version are you using?

Comment: I am ussing version 11

Comment: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b726adf6ed6e4423c2db9ac55548a3be

Comment: I resolved the issue. It was a constraint further down treating it like a string (`CONSTRAINT valid_ip_address CHECK(ip_address ~ '[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}')`) which was causing the problem. Will request to close

Comment: An `inet` type can't store invalid addresses, so the check constraint isn't needed to begin with